# Xcode 4, using breakpoints to log or po an object

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to use the log or debug commands in adding actions to a breakpoint.  I can't seem to figure it out.  For something like this:

```
double currentZoom = [self getZoomScale];
```

How do I print out the currentZoom?  I tried using log as my action, and then doing

```
currentZoom: @(double)currentZoom@ // this didn't work

currentZoom: @(double)[self getZoomScale]@ // also didn't work
```

Can someone help me out with this and any other info I may need to log information with breakpoints?

And also a simple example for `po` an object.  Does `po` always `po` the description (as in you have to have overridden the description method?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but don't you just want to use `NSLog(@"%@",[self getZoomScale]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print your double with NSLog, add the following line:

```
NSLog(@"%f", currentZoom);
```

Now, if you want to use the debugger console...

If you want to print currentZoom in the console, you don't need po. Plain p would be enough.This is, type

```
p currentZoom
```

and it's going to show you currentZoom's value. po is for objects. Let's say you wrap currentZoom in an NSNumber.

```
NSNumber currentZoomNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentZoom];
```

Then, to print the value, you would have to do

```
po currentZoomNumber
```

Like i said, po is to print objects, it means print object. So you can use it to print any type of object, from NSStrings and NSNumbers to NSDictionaries and NSManagedObjects.

Comment: nice answer, I really prefer GDB! If some one wants similar to NSLog to print object go for CFShow().

Answer (score 1):

You can make the breakpoint execute debugger commands.

Open the edit breakpoint pane:

[image: edit breakpoint pane].

Then type a debugger command (selecting "Automatically continue after evaluating" is advised).

To insert some context around the automated debugger commands, you can add another debugger action of type "Log Message". The "Log Message" action is not capable of inspecting variables itself.

`NSLog()` is probably easier to implement, but requires you to change the code you are debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to add actions to a breakpoint.  (I am interested in seeing it in any other answers offered)

The gdb syntax for printing objects is

```
po objectName
```

The gdb syntax for printing C variables is

```
print (int) intNum
print (float) floatNum
```